# Why would legendary villain "El Macho" have jumped into a volcano?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, despicable-me-2

In *Despicable Me 2*, Gru tells Lucy the alleged story of the last days of legendary criminal "El Macho", mentioning how he ended like he had lived, riding a shark-attached-dynamite-ladden-rocket into an active volcano.

I did not get why El Macho would get involved in such a fatal activity in this story. According to the legend, would it have been because he was trying to prove his strength, hoping he would survive such a dangerous deed?

Answer (score 4):

El Macho had a tendency to do impossible and dangerous task. The jump into the volcano was just one of his feats to prove that strength.

According to legend, he didn't survive that jump. However, it is also possible that he knew that he wouldn't survive it.

He did this jump, maybe in real or not, to fake his death, so he can run some covert operations without world's police running after him.

In the end, when Gru finds his secret lab, they have following conversation.

```
            GRU
      Nobody believed me! Ho ho!     But I
      knew you weren't dead!
     DESPICABLE ME 2           CINCO & KEN DRAFT    82.


                 EL MACHO
          (laughing)
      Of course not. I merely faked my
      death, ha, ha!
          (beat)
      But now it's time for me to make a
      spectacular return to evil!
```

In this conversation, we can see El Macho confessing about his fake death. He wanted to rule the world by unleashing those purple-colored minions.

```
            EL MACHO (CONT'D)
      Soon I will unleash them on the
      world--and if anyone, anyone,
      tries to stop them...YEOW! Their
      city gets eaten!
          (beat)
      We can do it together!

                   GRU
      Together?

                EL MACHO
      Together! I have admired your work
      for years, amigo. Stealing the
      moon?! Are you kidding?! We would
      be unstoppable! Men like you, men
      like me, we should be ruling the
      world!
```

[Script Source](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Despicable-Me-2.html)

Comment: Faking the death seems the reason to me rather than proving something. Why did you use preformatted text? Block quotes look better IMO.